# Why does every noncompact orientable surface have a complex structure?

Tags: differential-topology, surfaces

There is a high-powered proof of the fact that orientable noncompact surfaces have free fundamental group [here](https://mathoverflow.net/q/18454/40804) that invokes the ability to put a complex structure on any such surface. But why should your favorite noncompact orientable surface actually *have* a complex structure? I seem to remember a theorem that noncompact orientable surfaces can be embedded in the plane, which would certainly do the job, but I can't find a reference.

Comment: Every oriented connected noncompact surface admits an immersion (not an embedding) into the plane. This is a special case of the Hirsh - Smale theory but can be also easily proven directly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given a Riemannian metric, giving a compatible almost complex structure is equivalent to giving a reduction of the holonomy group from $O(n)$ to $U(n)$. An orientable surface must have holonomy group in $SO(2)$, which is just $U(1)$, so the parallel transport automatically preserves a compatible almost complex structure chosen at some point. And in two dimensions, the Nijenhuis tensor automatically vanishes so an almost complex structure is complex. None of this called on compactness.

The countable connect sum of tori is an example of a noncompact orientable surface that doesn't embed in the plane, unless I'm being silly.

Comment: Good to know. Could you also recommend an intro to complex structure?

Comment: I have a rather overwrought proof that the punctured torus doesn't embed into the plane, but I couldn't manage to prove yours doesn't.

Comment: The punctured torus doesn't embed because that would extend to an embedding of the torus, since every circle in the plane bounds a disk. Similarly an embedding of the surface of countable genus would restrict to an embedding of the punctured torus. @Troy Woo Huybrechts has the best book on complex manifolds.

Comment: Of course you mean $O(2n)$ here.

Comment: I think you should edit $O(n)$ to be $O(2n)$.

Comment: Note that $O(n)$ and $O(2n)$ are two different groups.

Comment: @MikeMiller I don't want to rush into any rash modifications...

Comment: You're right, my mistake. What I said only holds for $n>0$.

Comment: Your answer is incorrect for $n \neq 0$.

Comment: @Mike Miller let us continue this conversation in chat.

Comment: $O(2n)$ has a split surjection onto $\Bbb Z/2$, while $O(n)$ doesn't, at least for $n$ odd and positive (see previous comments). So they are provably not the same. You might edit your answer appropriately.