# Any two dimensional orientable manifold is complex

Tags: riemann-surfaces

Let $M$ be a $2$-dimensional orientable manifold. Is $M$ a Riemann surface? If it is true, how can I show it? Thank you very much.

Comment: It is a $1$-dimensional complex manifold (in complex sense).

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/907476/534616

Comment: Not quite a duplicate of that one because the surface isn't required to be compact

Comment: I do not see why they answer my question.

Comment: @joseabp91  Isn't it the definition of the Riemann surface?(See here:https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface.   In fact,dimension-two differentiable manifold naturally admits an almost complex structure and it is intergrable.Then it determines a complex structure (By Newlander-Nierenberg's theorem) .

Comment: By the way,any $n$-dimension  complex is an oriented $2n$-dimension differentiable manifold shows the equivalence of the definition.