# Every closed orientable surface is Riemann surface

Tags: manifolds, surfaces, riemann-surfaces, complex-manifolds

I want to prove that every closed orientable surface is a Riemann surface i.e. every closed orientable surface admits a complex structure. Several proofs are available which make use of classification theorem for closed surfaces. How can one prove this without assuming the classification theorem?

Comment: Although [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/907437/why-does-every-noncompact-orientable-surface-have-a-complex-structure?rq=1) *asks* only about the non-compact case, the accepted answer explicitly covers the compact case as well.

Comment: See also [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1661331/proof-of-equivalence-of-conformal-and-complex-structures-on-a-riemann-surface?rq=1): First, put a Riemannian metric on the surface, then use isothermal coordinates to define a holomorphic atlas.